# Bootstrap - css layout messed up after embedding external HTML as an object

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, object, tags

Bootstrap newbie here. I'm trying to break down my bootstrap template into multiple segments (i.e. title, footer, left nav, and main content) for re-usability and ease of updating.

The problem I have is when I try to import the external HTML file using the object tag, it messes up the CSS layout.

```
  <object name="foo" type="text/html" data="title.html"/>
```

When I don't use the object tag, it displays fine. However, if I strip out the "container" div into "title.html" and link it back in using the object tag, it fails. Is there a way to prevent that?

Here's a sample and the screenshots on what I'm trying to do:

```
<body>
<!-- start: Header -->
<header class="navbar">
    <div class="container">

        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-nav.nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a id="main-menu-toggle" class="hidden-xs open">
               <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>       
        <a class="navbar-brand col-lg-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-12" href="index.html">          
               <span>Home Portal Link</span></a>
     </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Screenshot 1: [Failed page when use object tag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3inCN7dc0yxdUpfUlNZamVzVTQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Screenshot 2: [Working page - not using the object tag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3inCN7dc0yxUFd3N2VRZGkyeW8/edit?usp=sharing)

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, the screenshot links were swapped, but you'll get the idea. Thks!

Comment: try using a static path to `title.html`? and try to add `width` and `height`?